# Text inset for UITextField?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I would like to inset the **text** of a `UITextField`.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565645/indent-the-text-in-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 651, accepted):

Overriding `-textRectForBounds:` will only change the inset of the placeholder text. To change the inset of the editable text, you need to also override `-editingRectForBounds:`

```
// placeholder position
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 10);
}

// text position
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, although I used a return value of CGRectInset(bounds, 9, 0); I also needed to set this value for textRectForBounds, editingRectForBounds, and placeholderRectForBounds.

Comment: This solution doesn't play well with clearButton. Text inside TextField overlays button.

Comment: I think, overriding above methods will cause scroll slow, if `UITextField` is residing within a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: For placing the ClearButton:

`- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
}`

Found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361369/ios-programming-frame-bounds-and-center

Comment: I suggest to call [super textRectForBounds:bounds] and [super editingRectForBounds:bounds] before calling CGRectInset(bounds,10, 10). This will fix the clear button overlay issue.

Comment: Note that you can avoid subclassing by using a category on UITextField.

Comment: I want to subclass `UITextField` in a way that I can pass padding in parameters in constructor or something. I don't want to create 100 subclass if I need text boxes with 100 diff padding.

Comment: swift 3 solution below                                                                                       `override  func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10);
    }`

Comment: The correct way to fix the issue with the clear button is to implement `clearButtonRect(forBounds:)`

Answer (score 303):

I was able to do it through:

```
myTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
```

Of course remember to import QuartzCore and also add the Framework to your project.

Comment: +1 for creativity, but this is a little bit problematic, it moves also delete button inside textfield

Comment: you could do myTextField.layer.sublayers which is an array of all the sublayers... and if its UIImageView <- I am assuming the X is an image.. or maybe UIButton... or you could loop thorough each one and see which one belongs to which subview... but myfield.layer.sublayerTransform all the sublayers and thus the X button moving as well..

Comment: This solution is not working for me. I can only set Left and Top margin but not right and bottom. `UITextField` overlaps content at right side of it.

Comment: Strangely, this technique does not work for a UILabel. Anyone know why?

Comment: absolutely a great solution. works with multiple uitextfields.

Comment: This is the best solution without subclassing and doesn't require extra, unnecessary views to be placed on screen! +1!

Comment: @Nikita which "delete button" are you talking about. Sorry for digging in an old thread. But, I want to know its cons to avoid future problems.

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat The X button on the right side in this picture.. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/Art/uitextfield_callouts_2x.png

Comment: For those trying to inset the textField on a searchBarController (so it's not so close to the icon, for example) `searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(10, 0)` is what you want.

Answer (score 183):

If you need just a left margin, you can try this:

```
UItextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:...];
UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, textField.frame.size.height)];
leftView.backgroundColor = textField.backgroundColor;
textField.leftView = leftView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

It works for me. I hope this may help.

Comment: This is far easier than subclassing just to get an inset, and lets you add any arbitrary view on the left (you can also use rightView to put something on the right). Better than the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: +1 easy, no-subclassing, and designed to work with textfield properties (rather than 'hacking').

Comment: Third line should be `leftView.backgroundColor =  textField.backgroundColor;`... Other than that great solution... Thanks (:

Comment: Not quite as elegant/thorough as azdev's answer, but a great solution for a common and simple case!

Comment: In case, there is a background image for the text field, how can we use this to set the inset ?

Comment: I was skeptical that this was the best solution, but honestly, short of a sub-class, this is the easiest and best solution IMHO

Comment: Subclassing will save you a ton of time over this answer, unless you have one single text box you need this for.

Comment: Add a method in a category could be even cleaner. Something like `[myTextField pad:10.0f edge:UIRectEdgeLeft];` Saves subclassing and flexible.

Comment: Perfect, thanks ! Much better than subclassing, I added a dedicated function in an extension. 
One comment though: it is better to use `leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`, because in the case you use *roundedRect BorderStyle* it will eat the left border.

Comment: Great solution! Works for me, I posted a version in Swift below. Thanks @roberto.buratti !

Answer (score 170):

In a class derived from UITextField, override at least this two methods:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
```

It might be as simple as this if you have no additional content:

```
return CGRectInset(bounds , 10, 10);
```

UITextField provides several positioning methods you can override.

Comment: yes, if you don't override editingRectForBounds you get the text when editing at the top left of the textfield. - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 10);
}

Comment: Just edited the answer to integrate editingRectForBounds method into

Comment: This seems to me a horrible hack - you would also need to override `- (CGRect)borderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;`

Answer (score 107):

How about an `@IBInspectable`, `@IBDesignable` swift class.

```
@IBDesignable
class TextField: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var insetX: CGFloat = 6 {
       didSet {
         layoutIfNeeded()
       }
    }
    @IBInspectable var insetY: CGFloat = 6 {
       didSet {
         layoutIfNeeded()
       }
    }

    // placeholder position
    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds , insetX , insetY)
    }

    // text position
    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds , insetX , insetY)
    }
}
```

You'll see this in your storyboard.

[image]

**Update - Swift 3**

```
@IBDesignable
class TextField: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var insetX: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var insetY: CGFloat = 0

    // placeholder position
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: insetX, dy: insetY)
    }

    // text position
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: insetX, dy: insetY)
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the effect on Y undesired, I don't want to shrink the rect for the text, rather nudge it down towards the baseline of the field. I adjusted the implementations to `let rect = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY + insetY, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
        return CGRectInset(rect , insetX , 0)`

Comment: And add this too if yo are using placeholder ` override func placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
     return CGRectInset(bounds , insetX , insetY)
  }`

Comment: Weirdly this (setting the insets in `textRect` / `editingRect`) affects the scrolling performance (on iOS 12 at least), when the text overflows the visible rect. With an inset of 15 it even stops scrolling.

Comment: @Ixx For you (and anyone else who comes across this): I discovered the issue on iOS 12+ has to do with an inset that leaves bounds too small for the font size... The text layout engine tries to fit the text into the bounds, fails, and still lays out (appearing correct but taking a long time to chew on it before giving up). The solution was to reduce the inset (or the font size) to make enough room for the text.

Answer (score 30):

If you have a clear button, the accepted answer won't work for you. We should also guard against Apple changing things in the future by calling `super`.

So, to make sure the text doesn't overlap the clear button, let's get the 'default' value from `super` first, then adjust as necessary.

This code will add a 10px insets on the top, left and bottom of the text field:

```
@interface InsetTextField : UITextField

@end


@implementation InsetTextField

// Placeholder position
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect rect = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 0);

    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets);
}

// Text position
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect rect = [super editingRectForBounds:bounds];
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 0);

    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets);
}

// Clear button position
- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect rect = [super clearButtonRectForBounds:bounds];

    return CGRectOffset(rect, -5, 0);
}

@end
```

Note: UIEdgeInsetsMake takes parameters in the order: *top*, *left*, *bottom*, *right*.

Comment: Using `textRectForBounds:` and `editingRectForBounds:` methods *without* `clearButtonRectForBounds:` on iOS 7+ worked for me.

Comment: `clearButtonRectForBounds:` just helps nudge the clear button to the left a bit. You may like to leave it out. My text field was on a dark background, and the clear button needed a bit of extra padding on the right.

Comment: Weirdly this affects the scrolling performance (on iOS 12 at least), when the text overflows the visible rect. With an inset of 15 it even stops scrolling.

Comment: @Ixx For you (and anyone else who comes across this): I discovered the issue on iOS 12+ has to do with an inset that leaves bounds too small for the font size... The text layout engine tries to fit the text into the bounds, fails, and still lays out (appearing correct but taking a long time to chew on it before giving up). The solution was to reduce the inset (or the font size) to make enough room for the text.

Answer (score 27):

Thought I would supply a Swift Solution

```
import UIKit

class TextField: UITextField {
    let inset: CGFloat = 10

    // placeholder position
    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds , inset , inset)
    }

    // text position
    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds , inset , inset)
    }

    override func placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, inset, inset) 
    }
}
```

**Swift 3+**

```
import UIKit

class TextField: UITextField {
    let inset: CGFloat = 10

    // placeholder position
    override func textRect(forBounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return forBounds.insetBy(dx: self.inset , dy: self.inset)
    }

    // text position
    override func editingRect(forBounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return forBounds.insetBy(dx: self.inset , dy: self.inset)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return forBounds.insetBy(dx: self.inset, dy: self.inset)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget

     `override func placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            return CGRectInset(bounds, inset, inset)
        }`

Comment: In Swift 3 you must use 'CGRect.insetBy()' method

Comment: In iOS 11 at least, if you override `textRectForBounds`, the placeholder is also affected - so adding the placeholder override insets the placeholder another 10pt further. If that's what you're looking for, , but if not, it's good to be aware of.

Comment: Weirdly this affects the scrolling performance (on iOS 12 at least), when the text overflows the visible rect. With an inset of 15 it even stops scrolling.

Answer (score 17):

**Swift**

```
 class TextField: UITextField {

    let inset: CGFloat = 8

    // placeholder position
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
    }

    // text position
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
    }
}
```

Comment: Weirdly this affects the scrolling performance (on iOS 12 at least), when the text overflows the visible rect. With an inset of 15 it even stops scrolling.

Answer (score 14):

For people, who are searching for a easier solution.

Add the `UITextField` inside a `UIView`. To simulate an inset around text field I keep 10 px left and width is 20px less than the view. For a rounded corner border around the textfield, use the view's border

```
viewBG.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
viewBG.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
viewBG.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Comment: Honestly just putting a UIView behind the UITextField is the best and simplest solution. Make the UITextField transparent and done. I aligned it with a UITextView - turns out to be about 6 pixels inset. Much easier and also more flexible than creating a subclass...

Comment: A problem with this approach is the location of where the scroll bar will appear.

Comment: @DougAmos What scrollbar? Are you referring to `UITextView` perhaps?

Comment: The downside of this is that not the whole area is "tappable" and gives focus to the UITextField

Answer (score 14):

Using `textRectForBounds:` is the correct approach. I have wrapped this up in my subclass so you can simply use `textEdgeInsets`. See [SSTextField](https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit/blob/master/SSToolkit/SSTextField.h).

Comment: This approach, along with using cocoapods to import the SSToolkit pod, works great - i think this is the neatest way to go.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 14):

You can set text inset for UITextField by setting the leftView.

Like this:

```
UITextField *yourTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5)];
leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
yourTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
yourTextField.leftView = leftView;
```

Comment: When you also need to use left view for an icon, this cant work

Comment: @Reaper this method will also work for an image. add the amount of padding you want to the width of the imageview frame and set contentmode to center. ```imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageView.image!.size.width + 16.0, imageView.image!.size.height)```

Comment: this is way too hacky. there is already a textRectForBounds method for setting the inset

Answer (score 14):

**Swift**

```
    // adjust place holder text
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, usernameOrEmailField.frame.height))
    usernameOrEmailField.leftView = paddingView
    usernameOrEmailField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Comment: This is a really cheap and easy workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing, good job. It works like a charms.
Perfect for me.

Answer (score 13):

A good approach to add padding to UITextField is to subclass UITextField and add an edgeInsets property.  You then set the edgeInsets and the UITextField will be drawn accordingly.  This will also function correctly with a custom leftView or rightView set.

**OSTextField.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OSTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;

@end
```

**OSTextField.m**

```
#import "OSTextField.h"

@implementation OSTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super editingRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Good answer. Supplies the missing property :-)

Answer (score 9):

Swift 5 version of [Christopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909856/7551807) with extra usage sample

```swift
import UIKit

private class InsetTextField: UITextField {
    var insets: UIEdgeInsets

    init(insets: UIEdgeInsets) {
        self.insets = insets
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not intended for use from a NIB")
    }

    // placeholder position
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
         return super.textRect(forBounds: bounds.inset(by: insets))
    }
 
    // text position
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
         return super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds.inset(by: insets))
    }
}

extension UITextField {

    class func textFieldWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UITextField {
        return InsetTextField(insets: insets)
    }

}
```

Usage: -

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private let passwordTextField: UITextField = {

        let textField = UITextField.textFieldWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 10, right: 15))
     // ---
   
        return textField
    }()

}
```

Comment: Besides not requiring` get{}` for getter-only calculated properties, in Swift 5, you don't need the return statement for 1-liners, so you can tighten up the use case a bit with: `let passwordTextField = { UITextField.textFieldWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets(top:0, left:5, bottom:0, right:15)) }()`

Comment: Works excellently, BTW, and it's an interesting approach. Mixed feelings about the obfuscation by adding the extension though. Not sure why not just let the class be public and make it clear you're instantiating a subclass of UITextField where you use it.

Answer (score 7):

I did this in IB where I created a UIView Behind the textView that was a little bit longer. With the textField background color set to clear.
 [image]

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 / Designable in Interface builder / Separate horizontal & vertical insects / usable out of the box

```
@IBDesignable
class TextFieldWithPadding: UITextField {

@IBInspectable var horizontalInset: CGFloat = 0
@IBInspectable var verticalInset: CGFloat = 0

override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.insetBy(dx: horizontalInset, dy: verticalInset)
}

override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.insetBy(dx: horizontalInset , dy: verticalInset)
}

override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.insetBy(dx: horizontalInset, dy: verticalInset)
}
}
```

usage:

[image: usage]

&

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4.2** version:

```
import UIKit

class InsetTextField: UITextField {

  let inset: CGFloat = 10

  override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
  }


  override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
  }

  override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
  }

}
```

Comment: Weirdly this affects the scrolling performance (on iOS 12 at least), when the text overflows the visible rect. With an inset of 15 it even stops scrolling.

Answer (score 6):

It's the quickest way I've found without doing any subclasses:

```
UIView *spacerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10., 10.)];
[textField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[textField setLeftView:spacerView];
```

In Swift:

```
let spacerView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:10))
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
textField.leftView = spacerView
```

Answer (score 5):

It's absurd you have to subclass, since `UITextField` already implements the methods, as @Adam Waite points out. Here's a swift extension that exposes a factory method, also available in our [categories repo](https://github.com/twobitlabs/TBLCategories/blob/master/Swift%20Extensions/UITextField%2BTBL.swift):

```
private class InsetTextField: UITextField {
    var insets: UIEdgeInsets

    init(insets: UIEdgeInsets) {
        self.insets = insets
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not intended for use from a NIB")
    }

    // placeholder position
    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return super.textRectForBounds(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insets))
    }

    // text position
    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return super.editingRectForBounds(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insets))
    }
}

extension UITextField {

    class func textFieldWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UITextField {
        return InsetTextField(insets: insets)
    }

}
```

Comment: The link in your answer is dead, can you please update it?

Comment: Fixed the URL @WendiKidd

Answer (score 5):

Here is the same subclassed UITextField written in Swift 3.  It is quite different from prior versions of Swift, as you'll see:

```
import UIKit

class MyTextField: UITextField
    {
    let inset: CGFloat = 10

    // placeholder position
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
        {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
        }

    // text position
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
        {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
        }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
        {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
        }
    }
```

Incidentally, you can also do something like the following, if you want to control the inset of just one side.  This particular example of adjusting only the left inset comes in handy if you place an image on top of the UITextField but you want it to appear to the user to be within the text field:

```
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
        {
        return CGRect.init(x: bounds.origin.x + inset, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width - inset, height: bounds.height)
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the positioning of the text within a text field by making it a subclass of `UITextField` and overriding the `-textRectForBounds:` method.

Answer (score 2):

I subclased UITextField to handle this that supports left, top, right and bottom inset, and clear button positioning as well.

MRDInsetTextField.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MRDInsetTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect inset;

@end
```

MRDInsetTextField.m

```
#import "MRDInsetTextField.h"

@implementation MRDInsetTextField

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _inset = CGRectZero;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _inset = CGRectZero;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _inset = CGRectZero;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setInset:(CGRect)inset {
    _inset = inset;

    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (CGRect)getRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds withInset:(CGRect)inset {

    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(
                         bounds.origin.x + inset.origin.x,
                         bounds.origin.y + inset.origin.y,
                         bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width - inset.origin.x - inset.size.width,
                         bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height - inset.origin.y - inset.size.height
                         );

    return newRect;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self getRectForBounds:[super textRectForBounds:bounds] withInset:_inset];
}

- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self getRectForBounds:bounds withInset:_inset];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self getRectForBounds:[super editingRectForBounds:bounds] withInset:_inset];
}

- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectOffset([super clearButtonRectForBounds:bounds], -_inset.size.width, _inset.origin.y/2 - _inset.size.height/2);
}

@end
```

Example of usage where *_someTextField* comes from nib/storyboard view with **MRDInsetTextField** custom class

```
[(MRDInsetTextField*)_someTextField setInset:CGRectMake(5, 0, 5, 0)]; // left, top, right, bottom inset
```

Comment: Thank you. One suggestion to your code though - why did you use CGRect for inset and not UIEdgeInsets?

Answer (score 2):

This is not as short as the other examples, but takes an entirely different approach to solving this problem. Note, the caret will still begin flush to the left edge but the text will be properly indented when typed/displayed. This works without subclassing if your looking for just a left margin and you are already using `UITextFieldDelegate` for your text fields. You need to set both the default text attributes and the typing attributes. You set the default text attributes when you create the text field. The typing attributes you need to set in the delegate. If you are also using a placeholder you will want to set that to the same margin as well. Putting it altogether you get something like this.

First create a category on the `UITextField` class.

```
//  UITextField+TextAttributes.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextField (TextAttributes)

- (void)setIndent:(CGFloat)indent;

@end


//  UITextField+TextAttributes.m
#import "UITextField+TextAttributes.h"

@implementation UITextField (TextAttributes)

- (void)setTextAttributes:(NSDictionary*)textAttributes indent:(CGFloat)indent
{
    if (!textAttributes) return;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [textAttributes objectForKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = indent;
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = indent;
}

- (void)setIndent:(CGFloat)indent
{
   [self setTextAttributes:self.defaultTextAttributes indent:indent];
   [self setTextAttributes:self.typingAttributes indent:indent];
}

@end
```

Then, if you are using placed holders make sure to use an attributed placeholder setting the same indent. Create a default attributed dictionary with the proper attributes, something like this:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 7;
paragraphStyle.headIndent = 7;
NSDictionary *placeholderAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
```

Then, import the above category and whenever you create a text field set the default indent, the delegate  and use the default placeholder attributes defined above. For example:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.indent = 7;
textField.delegate = self;
textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Placeholder Text" attributes:placeholderAttributes];
```

Lastly, in the delegate, implement the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method, something like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.indent = 7;
}
```

Comment: The assumption that `defaultTextAttributes` contains `NSMutableParagraphStyle` is quite dangerous.. I'd rather mutableCopy all of this.

Answer (score 2):

**A solution that actually works and covers all cases:**

- Should use `offsetBy` not `insetBy`.
- Should also call the super    function to get the original `Rect`.
- Bounds is faulty. you need to    offset the original X, Y. Bounds have X, Y as zeros.
- Original x, y can be non-zero for instance when setting the leftView of the UITextField.

**Sample:**

```
override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return super.textRect(forBounds: bounds).offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: 4)
}


override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds).offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: 4)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the option posted by roberto.buratti the fastest solution, here it is in Swift:

```
let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: textField.frame.size.height))
leftView.backgroundColor = textField.backgroundColor
textField.leftView = leftView
textField.leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally try avoid subclassing but this works if you have already:

```
// add a property 
@property (nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;

// and override:

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return [super editingRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you avoid subclassing? It _is_ a valid design paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

To throw in another solution that has no need for subclassing:

```
UITextField *txtField = [UITextField new];
txtField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

// grab BG layer
CALayer *bgLayer = txtField.layer.sublayers.lastObject;
bgLayer.opacity = 0.f;

// add new bg view
UIView *bgView = [UIView new];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
bgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
bgView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

[txtField addSubview: bgView];
[txtField sendSubviewToBack: bgView];
```

[image: Original UITextField]
[image: Fixed UITextField]

Tested with iOS 7 and iOS 8. Both working. Still there might be the chance of Apple modifying the UITextField's layer hierarchy screwing up things badly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comprehensive Swift answer that includes a leftView (custom icon) and a custom clear button, both set in Interface Builder with customizable insets.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class InsetTextField: UITextField {
@IBInspectable var leftInset:CGFloat = 0
@IBInspectable var rightInset:CGFloat = 0
@IBInspectable var icon:UIImage? { didSet {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16))
    imageView.image = icon
    self.leftView = imageView
    self.leftViewMode = .Always
} }

@IBInspectable var clearButton:UIImage? { didSet {
    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.setImage(clearButton, forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "clear", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 18, height: 18)
    self.rightView = button
    self.rightViewMode = .WhileEditing
} }

func clear() {
    self.text = ""
}

override func leftViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var height:CGFloat = 0
    var width:CGFloat = 0
    if let leftView = self.leftView {
        height = leftView.bounds.height
        width = leftView.bounds.width
    }

    return CGRect(x: leftInset, y: bounds.height/2 - height/2, width: width, height: height)
}

override func rightViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var height:CGFloat = 0
    var width:CGFloat = 0
    if let rightView = self.rightView {
        height = rightView.bounds.height
        width = rightView.bounds.width
    }

    return CGRect(x: bounds.width - width - rightInset, y: bounds.height/2 - height/2, width: width, height: height)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need this solution which also supports leftView and rightView.

```
class InsettedTextField: UITextField {

    private let textInset: UIEdgeInsets

    var rightViewInset: CGRect {
        rightView.flatMap { $0.frame } ?? .zero
    }

    var leftViewInset: CGRect {
        leftView.flatMap { $0.frame } ?? .zero
    }

    /// Init the text field with insets.
    init(textInset: UIEdgeInsets) {
        self.textInset = textInset
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        bounds
            .inset(by: textInset)
            .inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftViewInset.width, bottom: 0, right: rightViewInset.width))
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        bounds
            .inset(by: textInset)
            .inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftViewInset.width, bottom: 0, right: rightViewInset.width))
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        bounds
            .inset(by: textInset)
            .inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftViewInset.width, bottom: 0, right: rightViewInset.width))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change TOP and LEFT indent only then

// placeholder position

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

CGRect frame = bounds;
frame.origin.y = 3;
 frame.origin.x = 5;
bounds = frame;
return CGRectInset( bounds , 0 , 0 );
}
```

// text position

```
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

CGRect frame = bounds;
frame.origin.y = 3;
 frame.origin.x = 5;
bounds = frame;
return CGRectInset( bounds , 0 , 0 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick solution without subclass & also inspectable

```
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var textInsets: CGPoint {
            get {
                return CGPoint.zero
            }
            set {
                layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(newValue.x, newValue.y, 0);
            }
        }
}
```