# UITextField Vertical Alignment

Tags: iphone, vertical-alignment

Is there a way to vertically align text in a `UITextField` half-way between `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter` and `UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom` or do I have to go with one of those?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield

Comment: @titaniumdecoy It's not.

Answer (score 4):

You should subclass a UITextField, and override the following methods:

```
- (CGRect) textRectForBounds: (CGRect) bounds
{
  CGRect origValue = [super textRectForBounds: bounds];

  /* Just a sample offset */
  return CGRectOffset(origValue, 0.0f, 4.0f);
}

- (CGRect) editingRectForBounds: (CGRect) bounds
{
  CGRect origValue = [super textRectForBounds: bounds];

  /* Just a sample offset */      
  return CGRectOffset(origValue, 0.0f, 4.0f);
}
```