# How to add padding to UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text inset for UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield)

I have a textfield and a background image for it. If text is left aligned, first letter of the text is too close to the edge of textfield (doesn't look good).

[image]

How can i add padding to the left side of textfield?

Comment: This link here might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone

Comment: Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone - http://geekblog.vodpod.com/2011/03/04/ios-trick-add-padding-to-a-uitextlabel/ - http://icodesnip.com/snippet/objective-c/objective-c-left-padding-on-uitextfield-hack

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield