# Indent the text in a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

My question is as simple as the title, but here's a little more:

I have a UITextField, on which I've set the background image. The problem is that the text hugs so closely to it's edge, which is also the edge of the image. I want my text field to look like Apple's, with a bit of horizontal space between the background image and where the text starts.

Comment: Do you mean to set the text's insets? Then try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield

Comment: you can add a UIImageView with the image, add the text field on top of it and set the textfield's width accordingly... thats the easiest solution...

Comment: @lukya Unless he wants the tappable area of the text field to include the section with the image, in which case your approach will require an additional gesture recogniser and some code in order to hack it into working.

Answer (score 235):

This is the quickest way I've found without doing any subclasses:

```
UIView *spacerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
[textfield setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[textfield setLeftView:spacerView];
```

In Swift:

```
let spacerView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:10))
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
textField.leftView = spacerView
```

Swift 5:

```
let spacerView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:10))
textField.leftViewMode = .always
textField.leftView = spacerView
```

Comment: This is cleaner than subclassing, AND CORRECTLY HANDLES THE CLEAR BUTTON. Wish I could give +2.

Comment: i agree, +2 if I could. as soon as i read 'subclass' in the much-voted-up answer i groaned inwardly because it's always harder and more error prone to start fooling with drawing methods

Comment: Great solution, just translated this to Swift: 
`var spacerView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:10));
        textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        textfield.leftView = spacerView`

Comment: great stuff, especially because it doesn't involve hacking with subclasses!

translation to C# (Xamarin):

`var spacerView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 7, 10));
                myTextfield.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                myTextfield.LeftView = spacerView;`

Comment: @jsiodtb I've tried to use this in Swift, but it prevents my segue from being performed. Any idea why? I _am_ calling it in `viewDidLoad()`. It doesn't work in `viewWillAppear()`, either.

Comment: @arcrammer I've having the same problem i can get the segue to work by putting the call in viewDidAppear however no effect, very strange!

Comment: @Arcrammer You are not allowed to use the same view as padding twice ( which causes the error you described )

Comment: can't use negative text Indent :(

Answer (score 41):

You have to subclass and override textRectForBounds: and editingRectForBounds:. Here is a UITextfield subclass with custom background and vertical and horizontal padding:

```
@interface MyUITextField : UITextField 
@property (nonatomic, assign) float verticalPadding;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float horizontalPadding;
@end

#import "MyUITextField.h"
@implementation MyUITextField
@synthesize horizontalPadding, verticalPadding;
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + horizontalPadding, bounds.origin.y + verticalPadding, bounds.size.width - horizontalPadding*2, bounds.size.height - verticalPadding*2);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textfield.png"];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, bg.size.width, bg.size.height);
MyUITextField *textfield = [[[MyUITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease];
textfield.verticalPadding = 10; 
textfield.horizontalPadding = 10;
[textfield setBackground:bg];
[textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[self.view addSubview:textfield];
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but it does not account for the Clear Button when it's visible. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Awesome solution ! Cant believe Apple doesnt allow you to set insets for UITextField !

Comment: @RPM Since iOS 6.0 UITextView has a attributedText property,so you could set NSAttributedString with attributes NSMutableParagraphStyle + firstLineHeadIndent (and tailIndent for the clear button). But yes, it takes iOS 6.

Comment: For whatever reason, firstLineHeadIndent within NSParagraphStyle appears to have no effect on the way text is displayed in a UITextField in iOS 6.

Answer (score 27):

A good approach to add padding to UITextField is to subclass UITextField , overriding the rectangle methods and adding an edgeInsets property.  You can then set the edgeInsets and the UITextField will be drawn accordingly.  This will also function correctly with a custom leftView or rightView set.

**OSTextField.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OSTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;

@end
```

**OSTextField.m**

```
#import "OSTextField.h"

@implementation OSTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super editingRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Good and clean approach. Just to note for others reading this comment: There's a temptation to go with spaceView and assign leftView for text view, but when you have many text fields, will you duplicate the code all around by adding spaceViews to all your textField? Probably no, so go this sublassing if you have many text fields.

Comment: Neat solution. +1 for using `UIEdgeInsets` that is definitely the appropriate tool for the task at hand!

Comment: This works, I found the accepted answer to crash if those UITextFields were using autolayout.

Comment: Much cleaner than the most voted answer, IMO. Nice job.

Comment: I've tried the other solutions, they also worked but textRectForBounds is the correct way. Thanks Brody.

Comment: Excellent approach to even the general concept of creating a custom control, based on an existing one. I used this as a basis for porting over all my custom Swift controls to Objective-C and now the IB is no longer crashing when loading Designables. (I should add that my controls have IB_DESIGNABLE set)

Answer (score 14):

I turned this into a nice little extension for use inside Storyboards:

```
public extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable public var leftSpacer:CGFloat {
        get {
            return leftView?.frame.size.width ?? 0
        } set {
            leftViewMode = .Always
            leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.size.height))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one works perfectly. If you use it with @IBDesignable you can see it in the storyboard

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents:

```
class PaddedTextField : UITextField {
    var insets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    var verticalPadding:CGFloat = 0
    var horizontalPadding:CGFloat = 0

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + insets.left, y: bounds.origin.y + insets.top, width: bounds.size.width - (insets.left + insets.right), height: bounds.size.height - (insets.top + insets.bottom));
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting your `UITextField` to a `UITextView` and setting the `contentInset`. For example to indent by 10 spaces:

```
textview.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Comment: this is actually a good solution, not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: @Jeremie it's because this doesn't answer the question. UITextField and UITextView behaves differently and you would have to modify the text view significantly to get it to behave like a text field

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the leftView of the textField is a Apple's magnifying glass image.
If so, you can set an indent like this:

```
    UIView *leftView = textField.leftView;
    if (leftView && [leftView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        leftView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        leftView.width = 20.0f;  //the space you want indented.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create @IBOutlet's could simply subclass (answer in Swift):

```
class PaddedTextField: UITextField {

  override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()

      let spacerView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
      leftViewMode = .always
      leftView = spacerView
   }
}
```