# Indentation in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield, indentation

[image: For example, I want the "test" text a little bit right, what property should I set?]

UITextView indentation problem:

For example, I want the "test" text a little bit right, what property should I set?

Comment: Little bit right or completely right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565645/indent-the-text-in-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a subclass and override `textRectForBounds:` and `editingRectForBounds:`. Your new implementations may look something like

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
{
    return CGRectInset([super textRectForBounds:bounds], 10.f, 0.f);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
{
    return CGRectInset([super editingRectForBounds:bounds], 10.f, 0.f);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
    UIView *paddingView           = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    self.yourtextField.leftView             = paddingView;
    self.yourtextField.leftViewMode         = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: What id I want to indent from top

Comment: This is a hacky solution. The real solution is to override textRectForBounds: and editingRectForBounds: as Paul.s answered. What if you want to make use of that left view?

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this simple method....

```
textfield.frame = CGRectMake(textfield.frame.origin.x+10, textfield.frame.origin.y, textfield.frame.size.width, textfield.frame.size.height);
```