# button inside a uitextview

Tags: iphone, ios4

[image]I am having a uitexview in that would like to have uibutton.when tapping on that button i want do some actions.So i did as below

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 80);
    myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    myTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    myTextView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myTextView];
    [myTextView sizeToFit];
    [myTextView release];

    // Create an UIButton
    UIButton *pickerBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
    // Set its background image for some states...
    UIImage *pickerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picker.png"];
    [pickerBtn setBackgroundImage: pickerImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    // Add target to receive Action
    [pickerBtn addTarget: self action:@selector(showPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    // Set frame width, height
    pickerBtn.frame = CGRectMake(-25, -10, 50, 30);    
    pickerBtn.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    pickerBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    pickerBtn.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5]; 
    pickerBtn.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    pickerBtn.bounds = CGRectInset(button.bounds, -3, 2);
    pickerBtn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [myTextView addSubview:pickerBtn];
```

But what my problem is cursor shows even on that button.

Is there any better way to do wat i am trying now

Please let me know and thanks

Comment: Can you include a screenshot to help explain your problem?

Comment: what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: @jrturton :added image and thanks

Comment: @HardikShah:when click on that btn ,i would like to show picker to select , the selected text will get append into the textview

Comment: One with the cursor on top of the button would be nice ;). That looks very short for a text view, does it allow multi line editing?

Comment: check out the answer on [link][1] it may be helpful to you. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield

Comment: @jrturton : yes it supports multiline text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to measure the length of the text and put the button at the end text and when click on the show the picker and append the text.  i think this is way you can do.