# Change start text position in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, text, uitextview, alignment

Is there any way to change the start position of the text in a `UITextView`? Pretty much right now I am trying to align text with a lined paper picture and the text just does now line up properly.

Is there any way to change the position of the starting text (like higher or lower)?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield

Comment: this answer is for a UITextView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786632/how-to-change-the-text-position-inside-uitextview