# How to change the text position inside UITextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there away to change the postion where text in UITextView displayed. for example, i need the text to appear near the bottom of the UITextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Don't know surly that i am  right or not ??? but you need to use the `contentOffset` property of the `UITextView` class to accomplish this

For get more information [refer this documenttation.](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/)

Answer (score 1):

why not using an other view and placing the UITextView on top of that? so you can decide where to place it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the bounds, for the text to display at the bottom :)