# How to vertically align a UILabel used as a leftView in a UITextField with the textField's text?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm using a `UILabel` as the `leftView` of a `UITextField`. The issue is that the textField's text is higher than the label's.

This is the code I've used so far

```
UILabel *startsWith = [[UILabel alloc] init];
startsWith.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
startsWith.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
startsWith.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
startsWith.text = @"Text";
[startsWith sizeToFit];
self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self.textField.leftView = startsWith;
```

I've tried slightly changing the label's frame but it didn't work...

How can I align both texts?

Comment: You could try subclassing `UITextField` and then overriding `- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a container view in which you position the `UILabel` 1px up.

```
    UIView * v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *startsWith = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    startsWith.font = self.textfield.font;
    startsWith.textAlignment = self.textfield.textAlignment;
    startsWith.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    startsWith.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    startsWith.text = @"Text";
    [startsWith sizeToFit];

    startsWith.frame = CGRectOffset(startsWith.frame, 0, -1);
    v.frame = startsWith.frame;
    [v addSubview:startsWith];
    self.textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    self.textfield.leftView = v;
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you! Is there a way to reduce the horizontal space between the label and the text input?

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you can reduce it by reducing the leftview's width, in this case v's frame, I can't test it rigth now. If you need more special functioning, maybe the subclassing and method overriding is the best approach. Look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield).

Comment: reducing the left view's width made it! Thanks again!!

Comment: Nice. Don't even bother customizing leftVew with auto layout constraint. It's a hell of a pain in the ass :)