# Position text in a textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I would like to position the text in a textfield more specifically.

My current code:

```
UITextField * textFieldIndustry = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 465, 68)];
textFieldIndustry.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];  
textFieldIndustry.placeholder = @"Tap to..";  
textFieldIndustry.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

This code:

```
textFieldIndustry.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Centers the text but not exactly where I want it. How do I position using for example X & Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set position of text implicitly in UITextField **without subclassing** it.

You can use UITextView instead, and should use the same approach with it:

```
UITextView *textView;
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
[textView setContentInset:insets];
```

You can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2694478/611055) also with subclassing the UITextField.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed my problem by using a button instead of a textfield. The button allowed me to change the inset and still get the same result as using a textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize the leftView portion of UITextView to do what you are asking. This is great for adding a prefix to a textField without placing a label in front of it. I'm not sure exactly how you wish to use it but it may be a good solution. Basically you just create a UILabel (or any view) with the width and height you like then add that as the leftView of the textField.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple you just need to do textfield padding on which direction you want by using "UIEdgeInsets"

Ex: UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
    [textView setContentInset:insets];
It will show you the textfield after 10 pxls from .....like this you can give.

happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *textFieldNote = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 110)];
textFieldNote.placeholder = @"Ghi chú";
textFieldNote.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
textFieldNote.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

Comment: would you mind adding some description of what you did?

Answer (score 0):

For the `x`, you can create a padding by adding a view to the left side of the textfield.

```
    let padding = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: phoneNumberTextfield.frame.height))
    textFieldIndustry.leftView = paddingView
    textFieldIndustry.leftViewMode = .always
```

This ensures that the cursor is not at the edg