# Add padding to uitextfield using appearance

Tags: ios, uitextfield, padding

**I don't want to subclass the UITextField class just to get text padding.**

I want to do it using the appearance proxy.

I tried this:

```
UIView *padding = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 2)];
[[UITextField appearance] setLeftView:padding];
[[UITextField appearance] setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

unfortunately, if i put this code in my app delegate, any view controller that has a uitextfield in it, fails to load the view

how can I add padding to the textfield without subclassing it ?

Comment: this answer solves my question 


   http://stackoverflow.com/a/15558652/2136812

Answer (score 2):

```
Can you try these..

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    int margin = 10;
    CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width/2, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width/2 - margin, bounds.size.height);
    return inset;
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    int margin = 10;
    CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width/2, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width/2 - margin, bounds.size.height);
    return inset;
}
```

(Or)

do like this

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

 UIView *paddingTxtfieldView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 42)];// what ever you want 
 txtfield.leftView = paddingTxtfieldView;
 txtfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
 txtfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;// if you want to go next textfiled write this otherwise "UIReturnKeyDone"
```

Comment: I do not wish to subclass uitextfield... in order to write the above methods i need to subclass it

Comment: because it is an uneeded class just for a simple padding feature

Comment: see for more information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371018/uitextfield-leftview-rightview-padding-on-ios7

Comment: if the above answer helps u upvote the answer and mark it as correct answer