# iOS - Pull right view image of a text field from borders

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextfield

In my iOS project, i added an image to the right of text field. It leaned on borders at all. [image]

Then i searched and find [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371018/uitextfield-leftview-rightview-padding-on-ios7) and used TTillage's solution. It became better, but still leaned on top and bottom borders. [image]

Finally i changed the frame of my image, however pulling inside from right border was not working at this point. My final view is: [image]

I want this little image to be a bit away from borders and not stretched (if i do second version with third, it gets stretched). Is there a way for this?
My code:

```
    myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
    myImage.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 0.0, self.textField.frame.size.height-5.0, self.textField.frame.size.height-5.0);
    //myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    self.textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
    self.textField.rightView = myImage;
```

Thank you.

Comment: what happens if u uncomment the 'contentMode' line ??

Comment: In last version this content mode makes the frame alteration uneffective. Nothing changes. If i comment this line, third picture appears.

Comment: ok. Can u try the answer. see if it helps

Comment: Remove text field border, wrap it in UIView, add margins to it.