# How do I add X px of padding for left view images in UITextFields?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextfield

I currently have images loading for my text fields like

```
fullNameField.delegate = self
    fullNameField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    fullNameField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let fullNameImageView = UIImageView()
    let fullNameImage = UIImage(named: "FullName")
    fullNameImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 32, height: 32)
    fullNameImageView.image = fullNameImage
    fullNameField.addSubview(fullNameImageView)
    fullNameField.leftView = fullNameImageView
    fullNameField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

I can get everything to load but my frame for the image view isn't creating a 10 pixel padding to the right and down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextfield leftView/rightView padding on iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371018/uitextfield-leftview-rightview-padding-on-ios7)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using edge insets?

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(x, x, x, x);
```