# How can set right margin in UItextfield and also placeholder text?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

I tried to set the right side margin in `UItextfield` but I can't get success for this.

I tried below code:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 60, 25) ];
[lbl setText:@"Partenza:"];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
txtFCarat.rightView = lbl;
txtFCarat.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
txtFCarat.delegate = self;
```

Please help me if any body have a solution for this!

Comment: how much margin do you want to set on right side ?

Comment: i want to 10dp margin in uitextfield. @UndercoverDeveloper

Comment: Check the ansewer now ?

Comment: can't get friend. please explain me in brief. @UndercoverDeveloper

Comment: bhargav did you find solution.it will be better if you go overriding as per ur requirement

Comment: hey bhargav i had edited my post u can now go through it

Comment: I respect to your effort and Thank you for help me.@kamaleshkumaryadav

Comment: I respect to your effort and Thank you for help me.@UndercoverDeveloper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override this below two methods

```
@implementation rightTextField  

       // placeholder position

    - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
         return CGRectInset( self.bounds , margin position , margin position );
    }

    // text position
    - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
         return CGRectInset( self.bounds , margin position ,margin position );
    }
```

Edit: use to bind code like

```
textField.bounds = [self editingRectForBounds:textField.bounds];
textField.bounds = [self textRectForBounds:textField.bounds];
```

Your expected Answer:

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
    textfield.rightView = imageView;
    textfield.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: look who is talking about not copying the source and giving credit to original author http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield/3969703#3969703

Comment: @UndercoverDeveloper two methods are use like this way for all engineers.

Comment: I try this code but it is still lakeing same problem.I respect to your effort and Thank you for help me.@iDev

Comment: what problem you are facing  @BhargavNarola

Comment: I set background image on UItextfield . I use without border uitextfield. When i am set background image i faceing a problem is that Text which are display in uitextfield is on edge on uitextfield so i want to make a margin right side. This is i am facing. Help me. @iDev

Comment: @BhargavNarola could you post your screen shot

Comment: I can't upload image beacause i have not enough reputation. Give me your email id. Mr @iDev

Comment: @BhargavNarola raja.integrass@gmail.com

Comment: i shout out mail in your mailbox. check it. Mr @iDev

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line where you are creating textfield..and set value as per requirement

```
textField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-20, 000, 0);
```

Another way to achieve this by overriding the `textRectForBounds`

Let me to give complete Description how to do this or achieve it

1. First you create a class  and name "textField"(or what ever you Want) and must be sure that IT IS SUBCLASS OF  UITextField.

   2.Now open the `textfield.m` class and use this code or paste below code in this class (textfield):

   ```
    - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
      return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 50, bounds.origin.y,
                 bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height);
    }

   -(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
   }
   ```

If you want to customize the textfield more then you can use here only or in calling Class like

use the below code :Note it is only for testing purpose.it depend on your requirement

```
- (void)settingTextField {

[self setTextField];
[self setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
}



- (void)setTextField {
[self setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
[self setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[self setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0/225.0 green:120.0/225.0 blue:120.0/225.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
[self setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
}
```

3.improt textField.h class into your view-controller where you wants to create textfield

and you call it like this.

```
 #import "textField.h"

//Viewcontroller Class
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   textField *field1 = [[textField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 20)];
  field1.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
  field1.placeholder=@"0";
  [self.view addSubview:field1];
}
```

**Try to adjust the value `textRectForBounds` as per you reqitement**

Comment: In application i set Uitextfield alignment is right side. I try your code but it is not work for me. please help me. @kamalesh kumar yadav

Comment: at place of 20 make it -10(minus sign 10) and let me now

Comment: i set 20 instate of 10 but in that Uitextfield width in changes. I need to set right margin when text is display and edit . @kamalesh kumar yadav

Comment: now check the updated answer i was telling to make it -10 not just 10.just copy and paste the above code.Ihad made changes

Comment: little bit get success but one problem is there. we set -10 so Uitextfield width -10 decrease from origin width. but problem is there the text is being display in Uitextfield is also movie -10 from right side.

Answer (score -1):

```
    NSString *myString = @"Partenza:";
    UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
    CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont];

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myStringSize.width + 10, 25) ];
    [lbl setText:myString];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    txtFCarat.rightView = lbl;
    txtFCarat.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: devoloper: hello above code which you are mention i am try but can't work in my application.

Comment: how can? please hele me. @UndercoverDeveloper

Comment: @UndercoverDeveloper don't copy the code from original author.

Comment: Just suggesting him an answer, not copying

Comment: refer the link to original author and give a proper reputation to original post. mention source by author name or link

Comment: I have copied that from my work and made this run on my simulator, Havent copied anything

Comment: your previous answer is copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone

Comment: I respect to your effort and Thank you for help me.@iDev