# How to make the UITextField text input to start after 5-6 space characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, text-alignment

Use two TextFields or using label/view in background. Placing TextFields over some view/label/TextFields is not proper development. And placing label or view in left side isn't the proper way either

[image]

I didn't think below way is proper way. So i want a better solutions

```
UILabel * leftView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,7,26)];
leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

textField.leftView = leftView;

textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

How can we use following to achieve it

```
// placeholder position
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset( bounds , 10 , 10 );
}

// text position
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset( bounds , 10 , 10 );
}
```

I was able to achieve using . But is there some better way then this

```
Txt_SecurityAns.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
Txt_Email.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Take a look at [Add inset in UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield)

Comment: How to use  I didn't get it // placeholder position
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset( bounds , 10 , 10 );
}

// text position
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
     return CGRectInset( bounds , 10 , 10 );
}

Answer (score 1):

Set paddingView in UITextField...

```
UIView * leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,7,26)];
textField.leftView = leftView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: i don't want to add label or view etc. I want to achieve it using some programatic work out of TextFields

Comment: Refer this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield

Comment: How to use I didn't get it // placeholder position - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds { return CGRectInset( bounds , 10 , 10 ); } // text position - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds { return CGRectInset( bounds , 10 , 10 ); }

Comment: you have a class derived from UITextField & override at least this two methods...

Comment: Refer this url : https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit/blob/master/SSToolkit/SSTextField.h

Comment: Add padding to UITextField is to subclass with an edgeInsets property. You then set the edgeInsets and the UITextField will be drawn accordingly. This will also function correctly with a custom leftView or rightView set.

Comment: Thanks for your help i was able to achieve using  Txt_SecurityAns.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
    Txt_Email.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);

Comment: I m unable to post questions coz of negative marking can u help me out to remove negative marking