# How to set position of an icon added in UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

The email icon and placeholder text are hugging each other.

I want to add some space between them.

[image]

Below is the code I am using to create these fields.

```
// view for fields background
var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(35, 300, 300, 90));
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

// email text field
var email = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50));
email.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

var emailIcon = UIImageView();

var emailIconImage = UIImage(named: "email_icon.png");

emailIcon.image = emailIconImage;

email.leftView = emailIcon;

email.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

email.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;

email.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"E-mail",
    attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()])

emailIcon.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 15, width: 30, height: 20)

view.addSubview(emailIcon)
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text inset for UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield)

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to do this without subclassing is to give **EmailIcon width 10pts more than the emailIconImage width**. And then set **contentMode of EmailIcon to centre or right** according to your need.Here is the code in obj C hope you'll figure it out in swift:

```
EmailIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: emailIconImage];
EmailIcon.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, EmailIcon.image.size.width+10.0, EmailIcon.image.size.height);
EmailIcon.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;  //Or UIViewContentModeRight

textField.leftView = EmailIcon;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the position from its layer:

```
 txtemail.layer.position = CGPointMake(30, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITextField and implement the following method to place the placeholder text in a position that you want -

```
placeholderRectForBounds:
```