# How to add an icon / label inside a TextField in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to add an icon inside a TextField in Codename One, to get a simulare result to what is described in this other [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500313/how-to-set-position-of-an-icon-added-in-uitextfield).

I could not find an example in the API JavaDoc. Should I define a new component Style (UIID) for each Textfield with a different icon as background (although I am not sure it will yield the expected result) ? Or is there a smarter way to do it ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different ways that will produce two different results. The text field hint can accept an icon so something like:

```
tf.getHintLabel().setIcon(myIcon);
```

Will work when there is no text in the field and vanish when there is.

If you want the icon to stay you can just use something like this:

```
Container cnt = BorderLayout.centerEastWest(myTextField, new Label(icon), null);
cnt.setUIID("TextField");
textField.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
```

Comment: Thanks Shai! I found the first way much simpler since my TextField had rounded border and the Form background did not have the same color as the TextField one. By the way I used the "direct" method `setHintIcon()` like tf.setHintIcon(myIcon);

Comment: Forgot about `setHintIcon` ;-)