# UITextfield stability?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, autolayout, uitextfield

I have custom textfields that consist of only the bottom border and a left detail image, like so (my reputation isn't high enough to post images so here are permalinks):

https://41.media.tumblr.com/e34c604c3f1f4b25c63415cf5927f3b9/tumblr_nqwgy4pjPi1tupbydo1_1280.png

now the text field is just fine when the user is typing, even when its past all margins, However when the user moves on to the next textfield, the previous textfield disarranges :

https://40.media.tumblr.com/8932411ee98e839e5b9b7b9df56fe27b/tumblr_nqwgz0FxdU1tupbydo2_540.png

is there any solution to this??

Comment: following URL will help you in your problem
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/3969703/3977940

Comment: the answers are very depreciated, but i'll attempt @PravinTate

Comment: none of these methods were successful, the text field just blew up @PravinTate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all i had to do was use an equal width constraint on my Text Fields. That will keep them from blowing up when there's to much text's within the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems appears to be a lack of proper constraints
You should constrain the person icon vertically to the bottom of the textfield and horizontally to the left side of the textfield

Incase you don't know, you can do this by control dragging down wards.

[image]

then constrain vertically by selecting vertical spacing

[image]

if necessary, repeat for the horizontal spacing. If it is still unclear then [check out this youtube video on constraints and size classes.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DIwSTXY0awng&ei=SjmWVZq9LY77gwTe440o&usg=AFQjCNF0gYPcSqZir8SHsLfsi4OawyTVGQ&sig2=9ckdXDh2zplwbvT9bo1ZzQ&bvm=bv.96952980,d.eXY)

Comment: the image is added programmatically , and that still doesn't solve the issue of the text within the field, it stretches beyond the boundaries