# Swift UITextField padding top

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

I use UITextField and I want padding top.
So... How to in UITextField text padding top?

Sorry for my English:/

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text inset for UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield)

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then you want translate your text inside the textfield by y. `UITextField` have property know as `sublayerTransform` which can be used to translate the text. For example, to give a text view translate x by 10 and y by 10 you would use this code:

```
let titleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectZero)
titleTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = 
let shiftTextByX = 10
let shiftTextByY = 10
titleTextField.layer.sublayerTransform  CATransform3DMakeTranslation(shiftTextByX, shiftTextByY, 0)
```