# Adding space in UITextField After image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

[image]

My problem is that I have created a textfield which has leftviewmode as an image and the placeholder is in somewhere middle of textfield where the text editing should get start when user starts typing. So how to get my text started from middle of textfield just where the placeholder is. I cannot set the leftviewmode in imageview because I already added image there. What should I do?

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a_point30"]];
image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.image.size.width, image.image.size.height-10);
self.enterSource.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways; self.enterSource.leftView = image;
```

For example textediting should began from hello world placeholder.

Comment: You can set background image of textfield which is a rectangle with left icon on it. Dont take any imageview, then just set the placeholder and text as center view.

Comment: can you please post your code what you tried.

Comment: Any source code would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: i have added he code which set the 'A' image in left of textfield.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text inset for UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, dropDown.image.size.width+10.0, dropDown.image.size.height);
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
textField.leftView = imgView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: Thanks again..perfect.. but i am bit confused what happened in code?

Comment: There is nothing new. imageview's size is 10 px larger than image in width and content mode of imageview is left. so image always allign left so you will get 10 pixel blank space and after your text will display.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 2.2.1**, it will be something like this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ImageName"))
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageView.image!.size.width + 10, imageView.image!.size.height)
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Left
textField.leftView = imageView
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```