# How to to set the 'start position' of the text displayed in an UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Say I have a fixed size UITextfield, I want to "display" the associated text starting from the n-th character.

E.g:

Normal UITextField with text set to 'Hello World'

```
*************
*HELLO WORLD* 
*************
```

What I want, n-th=4:

```
*************
*LO WORLD   * 
*************
```

Some notes:
I don't want to modify the UITextfield's text (say: deleting the missing characters), the idea is that the whole text should be there, but the "focus" moved few characters forward.

Comment: did you try textInset ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield

Comment: @TejaNandamuri AFAIK, that will affect where the text starts/ends. -It will move the whole text, and will put me in the same situation.

Comment: If you aren't dead set on using `UITextField`, you can try using `UITextView` and calculate the position of your character and then scroll to this point.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `UITextPosition` when the textfield begins editing like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = [textField beginningOfDocument];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:beginning
toPosition:beginning]];
}
```

Just set the `UITextPosition` for whatever index of the textfield's text that you where you would like the cursor to be.